# How to prerender a Vue3 application?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, prerender, nuxtjs3

I try without success to apply a prerendering (or a SSG) to my Vue3 application to make it more SEO friendly.

I found the [vue-cli-plugin-prerender-spa](https://github.com/SolarLiner/vue-cli-plugin-prerender-spa#readme), and when I try it with the command line: `vue add prerender-spa` I have the error:

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')

After that I tried `prerender-spa-plugin` but I have an error when I make a `npm run build`:

> [prerender-spa-plugin] Unable to prerender all routes!
> ERROR  Error: Build failed with errors.
> Error: Build failed with errors.
> at /Users/myusername/Workspace/myproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/index.js:207:23
> at /Users/myusername/Workspace/myproject/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:148:8
> at /Users/myusername/Workspace/myproject/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3

What do you think about this? Do you have any idea?

Comment: The package you're using here got his latest commit in 26 September 2019, so it's safe to say that it's not really relevant anymore. Did you gave a look to [Vitesse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse) or even [Nuxt3](https://github.com/nuxt/framework)? Those are probably one of the best solutions available to date regarding SSG.

Comment: If you purely want to pre-render and nothing else, you can also use [this service](https://prerender.io/) but I rather use any of the 2 solutions above. Or even [this one](https://github.com/brillout/vite-plugin-ssr).

Comment: Hi @kissu thanks for these ideas. If I understand, the first step will be to migrate my code in Vite or Nuxt ? It seems to be difficult with my App in VueCli ? Thanks.

Comment: It's not that difficult. It can even be as simple as just copy pasting some of your files there (I'm assuming your project is not super huge overall).

Comment: Yes sure, I was just to confirm that it's the fisrt step to do ;) thanks

Comment: Mind if I post a simple answer basically saying "just use nuxt :p"?

Comment: No problem, I was just going to ask you a last tips. What is the best between Vitesse and Nuxt, in case of a small project (I have only 10 pages, maybe 15 in the futur).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nuxt3 is a really powerful meta-framework with a [lot of features](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/) and [huge ecosystem](https://modules.nuxtjs.org/). Meanwhile, it's in RC2 right now so not 100% stable (may still work perfectly fine).
If your project is aiming for something simpler, I'd recommend using [Vitesse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse). It may be a bit more stable and it's probably powerful enough (check what's coming with it to help you decide).

Some solutions like [Prerender](https://prerender.io/) also exist but it's paid and not as good as some real SSG (/SSR). Also, it's more of a freemium.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same error output until I found the [prerender-spa-plugin-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prerender-spa-plugin-next). Then I notice the latest version of [prerender-spa-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prerender-spa-plugin) was published 4 years ago and prerender-spa-plugin-next is continually updating. It seems like that prerender-spa-plugin-next is a new version of prerender-spa-plugin with the same functions. So I use prerender-spa-plugin-next instead of prerender-spa-plugin then everything works fine!

Here is my step:

1. install the package

```
npm i -D prerender-spa-plugin-next
```

2. modify vue.config.js like

```
const plugins = [];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const { join } = require('path');
  const PrerenderPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin-next');

  plugins.unshift(
    new PrerenderPlugin({
      staticDir: join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      routes: ['/'], //the page route you want to prerender
    })
  );
}


module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: true,
    configureWebpack(config) {
        config.plugins = [...config.plugins, ...plugins];
    },
};
```

3. build

```
npm run build
```

Then check the index.html under the dist folder you can see the page is prerendered.

Further usage refers to the homepage of [prerender-spa-plugin-next](https://github.com/Tofandel/prerender-spa-plugin-next#readme)

Comment: Does not seem to work .... https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5985#issuecomment-712091677

Answer (score 0):

Found and fix about the scss files to import.

In nuxt.config.ts use :

```
vite: {
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `
                  @import "@/assets/scss/_variables.scss";
                  @import "@/assets/scss/my-style.scss";
                `
            }
        },
    },
}
```

Now my 2 mains issue are : how to install vuetify properly, currently syles and components seems working but the JS not, for example, accordions don't expands on click.

And second topic is to have a i18n module, it seems that vue-i18N no longer works.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer